# Using v-bind and v-on instead of v-model vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I was using v-model to handle inputs in a form, I had to change it to bind props values, at first input was like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" v-model="username">
```

and now it looks like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" v-bind:value="modelData.username" v-on:input="username = $event.target.value">
```

`modelData` is coming in props. and it has `username`.

when Using model, in `data`, i had defined

```
data: () => {
  return {
    username: ""
  }
},
```

and It was working fine, but after changing it to `v-bind` and `v-on`,

My question is how I can now get the value of `username` in methods? as in past, I was getting it as `this.username` to get the value and also clear it as well but now how I can get username in

```
methods: {}
```

I have a button to save input

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" @click="validateFormAndSave($event)">Save</button>
```

When `validateFormAndSave` get called I can have `this.username` right now I cannot get the value? But the Vue Doc says `v-model` and `v-bind:value`& `v-on:input` are the same?

UPDATE:

There can be and cannot be some value already there in username, as it being filled with `props` value, So `v-on:input="username = $event.target.value"` don't get the already written value but the only new one you entered? or edit it? Why is it so? is there any method for just to get what anyone typed in there or already been typed?

UPDATE:

This is getting very ambiguous. So for now.
1. I can set `v-bind:value`, But I cannot get it in methods without editing it.
2. I cannot set this.username = "" and it will not be removed from input as well. 
3. @input only get what you newly typed not what already in there

Comment: why did you changed it to `v-bind` though?

Comment: I am using one same form to make it ADD and UPDATE. so when form open in the update, I am attaching data coming in props to inputs form

Comment: You can access `this.username` if you have username in data.

Comment: I have username in data but i am not using `v-model` and I cannot access this.username as well

Answer (score 5):

`v-model` is just syntax sugar for =>

```
<input :value="modelValue" @input="modelValue = $event.target.value"/>
```

If you want something else, it's very easy to do. Just change the update side to `onInput`:

```
<input  
    class="form-control"
    :value="username" 
    @input="username = $event.target.value"
>
```

Then

```
data: () => {
  return {
    username: ""
  }
},
mounted() 
{ 
  this.username = this.modelData.username;
},
methods:{
  consoleUsername() {
    console.log(this.username);
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks I have a question. let suppose you have bind a value for username already? and then you are trying to get it? `@input` is dealing when you change in input, how can you get the value which already placed there?

Comment: Also I have this `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" v-bind:value="modelData.username" v-on:input="username = $event.target.value">` and I also have `username` in data but i cannot have this.username as well

Comment: You can set the same prop value in your data object as  => mounted() {
    this.username = this.modelData.username;
  }.Check my edited answer.

Comment: knowing the fact that props coming from a parent component? they can still be set on mount? when child component get mounted. the modelData.username is not being even set yet. then how it will work?

Answer (score 0):

The best possible solution can be when you are getting your data from props and also loading it a form for `v-models`.

Using `watch` feature of Vue component.

First I added props as

```
  export default {
    props: ["vendorModelData"],
```

and then I pass it through the `watch` to `v-model`

```
watch: {
  vendorModelData() {
    this.updatePropsValue(this.vendorModelData)
    console.log("data updated")
  }
},
```

in this way, it always loads differently when Props get changed.  This way I got be using `v-model` as well as load data from props to it.

I found it useful for me.