# How do I set a default value for v-model using computed property

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I have two input fields for dates: to and from.

I want the user to be able to select dates that I will send a request to the backend. That is why I am using a computer property - in the setter I will validate the dates to make sure from is less than to and to is not less than from.

How do I set default values for those inputs?

I am using computed properties so I can set default values for both inputs. One value is set to now, the other is 1 week ago.

```
<template>
<div class="logs-listing-table">
    <div class="mb-1 filter-actions-wrapper">
    <input type="date" v-model="this.fromDate">
    <input type="date" placeholder="this.toDate">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BnbReport',
  data () {
    return {
        fromDate: this.fromDateDefault(),
        toDate: this.toDateDefault()
    }
  },
  computed: {
    fromDateDefault () {
      var previousPeriod = new Date()
      previousPeriod.SetDate(previousPeriod.getDate() - 7)
      previousPeriod.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
      this.fromDate = previousPeriod
      return this.fromDate
      },
      toDateDefault () {
          var today = new Date()
          today.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
          this.toDate = today
          return this.toDate          
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

However, eslint throws me an error:

> Unexpected side effect in "fromDateDefault" computed property

> Unexpected side effect in "toDateDefault" computed property

Comment: You can use computed properties in your v-model like that ` <input type="date" v-model="fromDateDefault">` and leave the v-model empty. if you want to check that the dates are in your range, you can use a **watcher** or a method before sending.

Comment: What do you mean leave the v-model empty? Also what do I leave in data in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add get and set functions into your computed property.

**HTML:**

```html
<input type="date" v-model="fromDateDefault">
```

**JS:**

```js
computed: {
    fromDateDefault: {
      get() {
        //your validation
        return this.fromDate;
      },
      set(val) {
        this.fromDate = val;
      },
    },
  }
```

You can read more about the setters and getters in the official doc:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#computed-properties

Comment: Alternate Solution => https://stackoverflow.com/a/54783280/8150371